# How to have status 200 instead 404 for SAP hosted on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've set up a Google Cloud Storage bucket as a static website with an index.html as the main page and an index.html for error pages. The challenge I'm facing is that the content in the bucket should display a specific page for each client based on the path, which contains the client's ID (e.g., https://example.com/client/12345). There are no files named after client IDs in the bucket.

While the rendering appears correctly, my browser's console displays 404 responses. How can I prevent these 404 responses while still rendering the client-specific pages as expected?

Tried configurign the bucket with both the principal and notFoundPage to index.html